# Space in Postcode

Tags: php

I have a script that requires the postcode input to have a space in it, if not it will fail. Straight forward, but UK  postcodes can have gaps in different places, i.e W1 4SB, NW2 6PT or SG14 1LB how would I change users input, if there is no gap entered to the correct format using PHP?

Comment: The gap is always in the same place -- immediately prior to the last digit and two letters

Comment: People may want to check the official rules. People here assume the 3rd element (where 3rd is 3 in AB12 3CD) is only ever 1 digit. Source: http://www.royalmail.com/delivery/mail-advice/postcodes-addresses-explained

Comment: Are they *supposed* to have a space? Royal Mail say that it should, but is there an official source? Now that mail in the UK has been demonopolised.

Comment: @DavidYell The service may have been demonopolised, but Royal Mail is still the official source for Post Code data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked is:

```
$postcode = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['postcode']));
$test = $postcode;
if(substr($test, -3) == " ") {
  $postcode = $postcode; 
  } 
  else {
  function stringrpl($x,$r,$str)
    {
    $out = "";
    $temp = substr($str,$x);
    $out = substr_replace($str,"$r",$x);
    $out .= $temp;
    return $out;
    }

    $test = stringrpl(-3," ",$test);
$postcode = $test;
  }
```

Comment: i would also remove double whitespaces if someone enters postcode with  whitespace - preg_replace('/\\s+/', ' ',$postcode)

Comment: I would also check if the first letter is O or 0 and i or 1

Answer (score 7):

[Postcodes always end with digit-letter-letter](http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/gdsc/html/frames/Postcode.htm). Simply look for a space at the 4th character before the end of the string and if it's not there, insert it.

Comment: not true, there are A9 9AA, A9A 9AA and AA9A 9AA. Looking for the 4th character does not help.

Comment: @Claudiu You have misread my post. 4th **FROM THE END**. All postcodes end with 9AA format regardless of how many they have at the start.

Answer (score 5):

The space is actually always at the same position for fully qualified UK Postcodes. It is just before the last 3 digit/letters

So first validate that it is a real UK postcode and it matches the format, then do this:

```
$postcode = 'E154EZ';
if( isValidPostcode($postcode) ){
  $postcode = str_replace(' ','',$postcode);
  $postcode = wordwrap($postcode, strlen($postcode)-3,' ', true);
}
```

PS. You can get the UK Postcode validation regexes + extra info from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_postcodes#Validation)

Comment: It's just a dummy function I placed to indicate where you should validate the postcode. you can actually implement the function just by using the regex in the link I posted.

Comment: This isn't quite right. W7 2JD is a valid postcode, the above code makes it "W7 2J D". ```php > $stripped = str_replace(' ','','W7 2JD');
php > echo wordwrap(str_replace(' ','',$stripped),strlen($stripped)-3,' ', true);``` .

Comment: This seems to do it instead of the wordwrap line: `substr_replace('W72JD',' ',-3,0);`

Answer (score 4):

Two functions that are useful for preparing and validating postcodes:

```
function prep_postcode($str){
    $str = strtoupper($str);
    $str = trim($str);
    if(substr($str, -4, 1) != ' ')
        $str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - 3) . " " . substr($str, -3);
    return $str;
}

function is_postcode($postcode){
    $postcode = str_replace(' ','',$postcode);
    return
        preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{2}$/", $postcode)
        || preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/", $postcode)
        || preg_match("/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/", $postcode);
}
```

Usage example:

```
$postcode = prep_postcode($postcode);
if(is_postcode($postcode)){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's always in the same place (based on your examples), you could do this:

```
<?php
//...assuming postalcode has already been loaded into $postalcode...

//If the fourth-to-last char isn't a space, add one in that position
if (substr($postalcode, -4, 1) != " ") {
    $postalcode = substr($postalcode, 0, strlen($postalcode) - 3).
                  " ".substr($postalcode, -3);
}

//do whatever with $postalcode you'd normally do...
?>
```

Probably want to do some more checking around that, like it is a min length, etc.  But that should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pcode_title = trim(strip_tags($_GET['pcode_title']));
$pcode_title = eregi_replace(" ", "", $pcode_title);
$pcode_first = substr($pcode_title, 0, -3); 
$pcode_last = substr($pcode_title, -3); 
$postcode = "$pcode_first"." "."$pcode_last";
```

Answer (score 0):

function below will valid postcode first, if not valid, returns false. if valid, it will return a postcode with space between outcode and incode, no matter you give it a postcode with space or not.

```
function checkPostcode (&$toCheck) {
  // Permitted letters depend upon their position in the postcode.
  $alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                          // Character 1
  $alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                          // Character 2
  $alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkpmnrstuvwxy]";                            // Character 3
  $alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                     // Character 4
  $alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                             // Character 5

  // Expression for postcodes: AN NAA, ANN NAA, AAN NAA, and AANN NAA with a space
  $pcexp[0] = '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})([[:space:]]{0,})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

  // Expression for postcodes: ANA NAA
  $pcexp[1] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha3.'{1})([[:space:]]{0,})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

  // Expression for postcodes: AANA NAA
  $pcexp[2] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha4.')([[:space:]]{0,})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';

  // Exception for the special postcode GIR 0AA
  $pcexp[3] =  '^(gir)(0aa)$';

  // Standard BFPO numbers
  $pcexp[4] = '^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$';

  // c/o BFPO numbers
  $pcexp[5] = '^(bfpo)(c\/o[0-9]{1,3})$';

  // Overseas Territories
  $pcexp[6] = '^([a-z]{4})(1zz)$/i';

  // Load up the string to check, converting into lowercase
  $postcode = strtolower($toCheck);

  // Assume we are not going to find a valid postcode
  $valid = false;

  // Check the string against the six types of postcodes
  foreach ($pcexp as $regexp) {

    if (ereg($regexp,$postcode, $matches)) {

      // Load new postcode back into the form element  
          $postcode = strtoupper ($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches [3]);

      // Take account of the special BFPO c/o format
      $postcode = ereg_replace ('C\/O', 'c/o ', $postcode);

      // Remember that we have found that the code is valid and break from loop
      $valid = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Return with the reformatted valid postcode in uppercase if the postcode was 
  // valid
  if ($valid){
      $toCheck = $postcode; 
        return true;
    } 
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: ereg and ereg_replace were both derprecated by PHP 5.3.