# Blank space in UK postal code

Tags: postal-code

Is there a way to know where the blank space has to be, in an UK postal code, if the user doesn't write the postal code with the blank space?

For example, if the input is: `EC1A1BB, W1A0AX, M11AE, B338TH, CR26XH, DN551PT` then the output must be: `EC1A 1BB, W1A 0AX, M1 1AE, B33 8TH, CR2 6XH, DN55 1PT`.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space in Postcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013091/space-in-postcode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space is always before the final three characters.

This graphic shows the format:

[image: Format of a UK postcode]

Source: [GetTheData](https://www.getthedata.com/postcode)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Would be even more helpful if it were correct, e.g. LLNA_NLL

Comment: @chrisjshields thank you for pointing this out, a newer version of the graphic has the correct format, which I have added to my updated answer.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in R? I have UK postcodes without the space and need to get a new variable of the postcode with the space. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've created a C# method to validate postcode:

```
private string ValidatePostcode(string postcode)
{
    if (!postcode.Substring(postcode.Length - 4, 1).Equals(" "))
    {
         postcode = postcode.Insert(postcode.Length - 3, " ");
    }
    return postcode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The space seems to fall before the last three characters. Postcodes always end with Digit-Letter-Letter.

Answer (score 1):

The space is always before the NLL suffix.
The prefix can be 3 or 4 characters before the space. LLNA_NLL.
The above graphic is wrong! Should end NLL.

Comment: The format in the graphic has now been corrected.